# Error reported in typeof definition - argument undeclared

Tags: c, typeof

Getting this error on code that is part of the cairo graphics library needed to build NCAR graphics:
error: name undeclared here (not in a function),
in the line marked with arrows below.

```
#define DLCALL(name, args...) ({ \
  >> static __typeof (&name) name##_real; \ <<
    if (name##_real == NULL) { \
        name##_real = (__typeof__ (&name))(dlsym (_dlhandle, #name));   \
        if (name##_real == NULL && _dlhandle == RTLD_NEXT) { \
            _dlhandle = dlopen ("libcairo." SHARED_LIB_EXT, RTLD_LAZY); \
           name##_real = (typeof (&name))(dlsym (_dlhandle, #name));   \
            assert (name##_real != NULL); \
        } \
    } \
    (*name##_real) (args);  \
})
```

Please advise on a possible fix.
TIA,
Steve

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: After some spelunking, I see a call like this:     
    DLCALL (cairo_script_write_comment, ctx, "--- fdr ---", -1);   with "cairo_script_write_comment" defined in a header file as: cairo_public void
cairo_script_write_comment (cairo_device_t *script,
                            const char *comment,
                            int len);

Comment: That seems right, are you sure the header has been imported at that point? In particular, if you call `cairo_script_write_comment(NULL, NULL, 0);` before that line, is there a compiler error? (it won't run properly, just to test the compilation)

Comment: Yes, I see the header file is included.  I added the test call DLCALL(NULL, NULL, NULL, 0) and it compiled ok.